# Launch safari with old loaded page from ios app

Tags: ios

I want to launch safari from ios application with previously loaded page in safari . Please help me how to do this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "with previously loaded page in safari".

Comment: let i have already open one web page in safari . Then from ios app i want to launch safari , and i am expecting same page in safari after launch

Comment: Am still not sure what you mean, theoretically when you open a website from your app and if you were calling Safari, it will launch the website in a new tab. Also your question is super vague, what programming language are you using, any frameworks, what iOS version are you targeting etc.. etc...

Comment: I think you need to create a `UIWebView` instance and use this same instance for each subsequent url since safari will always open a new tab.